# Populate a UITableView with variables

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, populate

I have a table and so far, I can populate it by adding values to an array in the code. But I want to use a textfield values and enter it there, the only problem is, if I do that I can only have one value, I want to pass a textfield value without overwriting the current cell.
Here is what I have:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  //[self fetchRecords];  

  titlestring = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"titletext"];
  detailsstring = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"details"];

  tabledata = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"titlestring", nil];
  tablesubtitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:detailsstring, nil];
}
```

Is there a way to use MyArray[i] = marry initWithObjectcs...

Thanks.

Comment: Is this piece of code relevant ?

Comment: Not sure, I just want to know how to add a variable to that array in the second slot

Comment: assuming you've correctly implemented table view datasource methods, this should be as simple as `[myArray addObject:myString]`...

Comment: Could you explain better your goal? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you is your problem.
But if you want to add objects to an existing array, you should use a NSMutableArray not a NSArray.